# ios: Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -1 to see invocation)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa, ios7

I am developing an application which include the payment gateway functionality within my app.

I am using xcode Version 5.1.1.

I am integrating Authorize .net sdk into my project. All the necessary setup has been done. But it gives me below error due to which i am getting stuck from last few days. I have not find any solution for my problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My Project "Framework Search Path" is:

```
    $(inherited)
    $(SDKROOT)/Developer/Library/Frameworks
    $(DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR)/Frameworks 
    $(PROJECT_DIR)
```

Please help and give me permanent solution to this problem

ERROR:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.reachabilityRef in:
    /Users/demo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoutoutCity-ecfuboehzdynacafsciafeowrugc/Build/Intermediates/ShoutoutCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutoutCity.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability-CC44CEE899F86958.o
    /Users/demo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoutoutCity-ecfuboehzdynacafsciafeowrugc/Build/Intermediates/ShoutoutCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutoutCity.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability-3851C02C41B30E6B.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_Reachability.localWiFiRef in:
    /Users/demo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoutoutCity-ecfuboehzdynacafsciafeowrugc/Build/Intermediates/ShoutoutCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutoutCity.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability-CC44CEE899F86958.o
    /Users/demo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoutoutCity-ecfuboehzdynacafsciafeowrugc/Build/Intermediates/ShoutoutCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutoutCity.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability-3851C02C41B30E6B.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability in:
    /Users/demo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoutoutCity-ecfuboehzdynacafsciafeowrugc/Build/Intermediates/ShoutoutCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutoutCity.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability-CC44CEE899F86958.o
    /Users/demo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoutoutCity-ecfuboehzdynacafsciafeowrugc/Build/Intermediates/ShoutoutCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutoutCity.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability-3851C02C41B30E6B.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Reachability in:
    /Users/demo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoutoutCity-ecfuboehzdynacafsciafeowrugc/Build/Intermediates/ShoutoutCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutoutCity.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability-CC44CEE899F86958.o
    /Users/demo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShoutoutCity-ecfuboehzdynacafsciafeowrugc/Build/Intermediates/ShoutoutCity.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ShoutoutCity.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Reachability-3851C02C41B30E6B.o
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have not get a single solution on google that can solve my problem.

Please help me.

Comment: Go to build Phase>Compile sources.check Reachability.m file.it may be appear two times.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding (cmd+shift+k)? You should also be using Xcode 6 if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the immidiate reply....

Yes in my project there is Reachability.m file appears twice. Yes thi s can cause an issue. So can u tell me what should i do now?

Comment: Remove the extra Reachability.m from Build Phase > Compile Source, then Clean & Re-build from Product menu

Comment: Yes that solve my issue. Thanks for your valuable and immediate reply.
Thank you very much.....